# Unable to apply io.spring.dependency-management Gradle plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am using the `io.spring.dependency-management` Gradle plugin in all our work builds and never had an issue with it. It just works.
Here are parts of my local setup:

```
build.gradle:

plugins {
    ...
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    ...
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Hoxton.SR8'
    }
}

settings.gradle:

pluginManagement {
resolutionStrategy {
    eachPlugin {
        switch (requested.id.id) {
        ...
            case 'io.spring.dependency-management':
                useModule("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:${requested.version}")
                break
        ...
```

When I try to build I can see in the logs:

```
Apply plugin io.spring.dependency-management to root project 'my-project' completed
...
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > A problem occurred evaluating root project 'my-project'
[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > No signature of method: build_97hpysomemorerandomshere.dependencyManagement() is applicable for argument types: (build_97hpysomemorerandomshere$_run_closure4) values: [build_97hpysomemorerandomshere$_run_closure4@2d5aa553]
```

To me this is just telling me the dependency-management has not been applied and such the functions coming with that plugin are not accessible.

I look at the spellings until I got tired and I am a bit out of ideas about what I am doing wrong.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: And why is there a `,` after `'1.0.11.RELEASE'` ??

Comment: Sorry. My mistake when typing the question. I don't have a comma in my code. I removed it to avoid further confusion